# При открытии NavigationDrawer на втором экране кнопкой "гамбургер" - открывается первый экран

Tags: android, actionbar, android-navigation-drawer, android-menu

Есть 2 активити.

Для каждого сделал отдельные "шторки". 
При свайпе все нормально, тоесть в каждом активити открывается своя "шторка".

Но, при нажатии на значок "гамбургера" во 2-м активити, происходит следующее:
шторка второго активити моментально появляется слева и пролькальзывает направо, и скрывается с зоны видимости и мы уже на экране первого активити.

Ошибки никакой не вылетает.

Может кто с таким сталкивался когда делал на разные активити разные "шторки"?

Объявление в 1-м активити:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

     mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_first);
     mNavigationDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_first_layout);

     setSupportActionBar(cToolbar);
     mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
     ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
     if (actionBar != null) {
         actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
         actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     }
 }
```

Обработка нажатия 1-е активити:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        mNavigationDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_first:
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Объявление во 2-м активити:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

     cToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_second);
     cNavigationDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_second_layout);

     setSupportActionBar(cToolbar);
     cToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
     ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
     if (actionBar != null) {
         actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
         actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     }
}
```

Обработка нажатия 2-е активити.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        cNavigationDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_second:
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень похоже, что у вас срабатывает одновременно `back` по стеку активити.
Попробуйте не передавать управление родителю после нажатия `android.R.id.home`

```
if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
    cNavigationDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Действительно, не закрыл if... Откорректировал и все срабатывает нормально! Спасибо огромное!